# no se completa la llamada a .done en ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

tengo la siguiente funcion

```
function deleteItem(item_id) {
    var invoiceData = {
        'idt_id': item_id,
        'inv_id': $('#inv_id').val(),
        'inv_number': $('#inv_number').text(),
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'invoiceDetailDelete.php',
        data: invoiceData,
        dataType: 'json',
        encode: true
    })
        .done(function (invoiceData) {
            if (invoiceData.success) {
              alertify.success(invoiceData.message);
              // mas codigo...
            }
            else {
              alertify.error(invoiceData.message);
            }
        })
        .fail(function () {
           alertify.error(invoiceData.message);
        })
    }
```

el archivo `invoiceDetailDelete.php` borra el registro correctamente y regresa...

```
$invoiceData ['success'] = true;
$invoiceData ['message'] = "Item Borrado con Exito!";

echo json_encode($invoiceData);
```

valor regresado es correcto

```
{"success":true,"message":"Item Borrado con Exito!"}
```

pero nunca se ejecuta el `.done`, el código nunca pasa por allí.

Cual puede ser el problema?

Gracias por sus comentarios.

Comment: Estás seguro de que no da error la función? has probado a implementar el método **fail** a tu petición ajax?

Comment: correcto, edite la pregunta y el código para adicionar el `.fail`, efectivamente, allí si llega el código y el array `$invoiceData` llega `NULL`, no entiendo... si `invoiceDetailDelete.php` envia el array con credenciales de exito, sera que estoy leyendo mal el array?

Comment: El método fail devuelve datos del error ocurrido por eso `$invoiceData` es `NULL`, haz un `console.log` de los datos que te devuelve para ver más a fondo lo que está ocurriendo con la función. `.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {console.log(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);});`

Echale un vistazo a la documentación oficial de las funciones de ajax

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0`

Comment: Ese error significa que la respuesta que estás obteniendo no es un JSON, seguramente en la llamada a tu php esté saltando algún error o tengas un `echo` o algo por el estilo que está imprimiendo etiquetas html o parecido.

Al ser una llamada GET abre en tu navegador la ruta de esta forma `invoiceDetailDelete.php?idt_id=1&inv_id=valor1&inv_number=valor2` y compruebalo.

Comment: `invoiceDetailDelete.php:8:string '4' (length=1)
{"success":true,"message":"Item Borrado con Exito!"}`

Comment: Intenta con el navegador ir al inspector y en la pestaña de Red selecciona XHR y revisa que te devuelve el ajax.

Comment: Mira  Raúl Monge, yo estaba definiendo el array asi `$invoiceData = [];` y lo cambie a `$invoiceData = array();` y ya funciono bien, cual es la diferencia...

Comment: No hay ninguna diferencia a no ser que estés usando una versión más baja de php 5.4

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: uso la 7.0.23, gracias por tu ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Una opción és utilizar el **.success**.
Si no, dependiendo de la versión del jQuery la función que quieres usar se llama **.complete** o **.done**

**Edit:**

En versiones mas antiguas de jQuery si que se usa la función de retorno **.done**, pero debe de haber quedado obsoleta. Ahora se usa **.complete**, que es lo mismo que el **.done**, de hecho en la documentación de jQuery sale solo **complete**:

> **complete Type**: Function( jqXHR jqXHR, String textStatus ) A function
>   to be called when the request finishes (after success and error
>   callbacks are executed). The function gets passed two arguments: The
>   jqXHR (in jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHTTPRequest) object and a string
>   categorizing the status of the request ("success", "notmodified",
>   "nocontent", "error", "timeout", "abort", or "parsererror"). As of
>   jQuery 1.5, the complete setting can accept an array of functions.
>   Each function will be called in turn. This is an Ajax Event.

Fuente: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Para tu código solo es reemplazar el .done por .complete:

```
 $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'invoiceDetailDelete.php',
        data: invoiceData,
        dataType: 'json',
        encode: true
    })
        // .complete
        .complete(function (invoiceData) {
            if (invoiceData.success) {
              alertify.success(invoiceData.message);
              // mas codigo...
            }
            else {
              alertify.error(invoiceData.message);
            }
        })
        .fail(function () {
           alertify.error(invoiceData.message);
        })
    }
```

Comment: Explica mas respuesta para que se pueda entender, agrega un ejemplo mínimo para que se entienda mejor.

Comment: Hola, te funciona con el complete?